# understanding email validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I am new to JavaScript and found this JavaScript code in the internet that validates the given email (no issue with the code) -

```
<html>
<h2>Email Validation</h2>
<script language = "Javascript">
function checkEmail(emailId) {
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailId)){
document.write("You have entered valid email.");
return true;
}    
return false;
}

function ValidateEmail(){
    var emailID=document.form.email;

    if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
        alert("Please Enter your Email ID")
        emailID.focus()
        return false
    }

    if (checkEmail(emailID.value)==false){
        emailID.value=""
        alert("Invalid Email Adderess");
        emailID.focus()
        return false
    }
        alert('valid');
        return true
 }
</script>

<form name="form" method="post" onSubmit="return ValidateEmail()">    
Enter an Email Address : <input type="text" name="email" size="30"><br>    
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">    
</form>

</html>
```

I have no issues with the code, but I somehow failed to understand what the regular expression `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` means. I don't understand what each and every part of regular expression means. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You think that's confusing...try this: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. Validating an email w/ a regex is tricky...see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation

Comment: Notice - this regex will freeze your browser window if a long invalid email is passed to it.  See http://jsfiddle.net/ocqn35sm/

Comment: /^\w+([\.\+-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^
Modified to be inclusive of the "+" character... for what it is worth. That allows the bradchesney79+spamtag@gmail.com format email addresses through.

...gmail allows you to append a "+anything" text chunk to your gmail account name. It isn't a gmail exclusive feature. No, I don't know an exhaustive list of which services allow it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. The two forward-slashes /.../ contains a regexe.
2. The leading ^ and trailing $ match the beginning and the ending of the input string, respectively. That is, the entire input string shall match with this regexe, instead of a part of the input string.
3. \w+ matches 1 or more word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore).
4. [.-] matches character . or -. We need to use . to represent . as . has special meaning in regexe. The \ is known as the escape code, which restore the original literal meaning of the following character.
5. [.-]? matches 0 or 1 occurrence of [.-].
6. Again, \w+ matches 1 or more word characters.
7. ([.-]?\w+)* matches 0 or more occurrences of [.-]?\w+.
8. The sub-expression \w+([.-]?\w+)* is used to match the username in the email, before the @ sign. It begins with at least one word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore), followed by more word characters or . or -. However, a . or - must follow by a word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore). That is, the string cannot contain "..", "--", ".-" or "-.". Example of valid string are "a.1-2-3".
9. The @ matches itself.
10. Again, the sub-expression \w+([.-]?\w+)* is used to match the email domain name, with the same pattern as the username described above.
11. The sub-expression .\w{2,3} matches a . followed by two or three word characters, e.g., ".com", ".edu", ".us", ".uk", ".co".
12. (.\w{2,3})+ specifies that the above sub-expression shall occur one or more times, e.g., ".com", ".co.uk", ".edu.sg" etc.

[Reference](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html)

Comment: In 8. this part is not entirely true -- "However, a . or - must follow by a word character" -- because you can have an email address where - is followed by @ -- for example like this word-@word.com

Answer (score 3):

Give a try here [REGEX](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=/%5E%5Cw%2b%28%5B%5C.-%5D?%5Cw%2b%29%2a@%5Cw%2b%28%5B%5C.-%5D?%5Cw%2b%29%2a%28%5C.%5Cw%7B2,3%7D%29%2b%24/)

you can find a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a break down of the regular expression piece-by-piece:

---

`/^`  => beginning of a line

`\w+` => any word (letters, numbers, and underscores) repeated 1 or more times

`([\.-]?\w+)*` => a **group** of *[an optional period (.) or dash (-) followed by any word repeated one or more times]* that can be repeated 0 or more times

`@\w+` => an at symbol (@) follow by any word repeated one or more times

`([\.-]?\w+)*` => a **group** of *[an optional period or dash followed any word repeated 1 or more times]* that can be repeated 0 or more times

`(\.\w{2,3})+` => a **group** of *[a period followed by any word that can be repeated **2-3** times]* that can be repeated 1 or more times

`$/` => the end of a line

---

By the way, here is a *really* good [Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://codular.com/regex) available on [Codular](http://codular.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`E-mail: <input type="email" name="usremail">`

It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

here you go. a visualizer for regex

[Regex Visualizer](http://www.regexper.com/) and A `JS Fiddle` [Regex Explained](http://jsfiddle.net/v8Vp9/)

Answer (score 2):

This validation code is WRONG for email addresses. In particular is does not allow addresses of the form first+last@domain.com. This is widespread error found on many commercial websites (but not stackoverflow -- congratulations!).

Comment: /^\w+([\.\+-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)

Modified to be inclusive of the "+" character... for what it is worth. That allows the bradchesney79+spamtag@gmail.com format email addresses through.

...gmail allows you to append a "+anything" text chunk to your gmail account name. It isn't a gmail exclusive feature. No, I don't know an exhaustive list of which services allow it.

Also, stop downvoting this Debbie Downer, he is spilling out truth. Maybe he is an asshole, but he is not wrong.

Comment: In order to allow longer TLDs (like `.domain`) I had to change the `{2,3}` to `{2,64}`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+[,;]?[ ]?)+$/
```

this little beauty will allow you to enter one or more email addresses in a string, ending with a comma or semicolon, followed by an optional space.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validchat(){
    $('#btn-input-email').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
            if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                $('#valid').text('');
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                $('#valid').text('Не верно');
            }
        } else {
            $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
            $('#valid').text('Поле email не должно быть пустым');
        }
    });
    $("#btn-input-text").blur(function() {
        var textlength = $(this).val().trim().length;
        if( textlength < 2 ){
            $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
            $('#validtext').text('Минимум 2 символ');
        }else{
            $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
            $('#validtext').text('');
        }
    });
    var valid = $('#valid').text();
    var validtext = $('#validtext').text();
    if((!valid || valid == '') && (!validtext || validtext == '')){
        return true;
    }
}
validchat();
function AjaxChat () {
    $('#btn-input-email , #btn-input-text').blur();
    var valid = validchat();
    if(valid){
        var email = $('#btn-input-email').val();
        var text  = $('#btn-input-text').val();

        var data = {
            email:email,
            text:text
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: location.origin+"/chat_block.php",
            //dataType: "json", ////Тип данных
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                if(!html || html == 'null') AjaxChat ();
                if (jQuery.html != "") {
                    var b_chat = $('.chat-customer').html();
                    var chat   = 'Вы: ';
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                    chat += '<span>';
                    chat += obj['text'];
                    chat += '</span>';
                    chat += '<br /><br />';
                    $('.chat-customer').html(b_chat + chat);
                    $('#btn-input-text , #btn-input-email').val("");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                //cosole.log('No result');
            }
        });
        $('#btn-input-email').remove();
    }
}
```